# Git commit hook - How to use the commit-msg hook to check for string in message?

Tags: git, perl, bash, hook

I need to make a commit-msg hook to check if the commit message contains "app.asana" in any part of this. I searched some references and documentation and I know I need to use the commit-msg for this. I have to make this using Perl or Bash.

Does anybody has a clue about this or somewhere I can look more examples to learn how to do it??

Thank you.

Comment: [This](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) might help.

Comment: I already been to this page but thanks. And after some more research I did it... It was actually really simple.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found an answer to my question. In case it may help somebody...

I just created a `commit-msg` file in `.git/hooks` containing

```
#!/bin/sh

test -n "$(grep 'app.asana.com/' ${1})" || {
        echo >&2 "ERROR: Commit message is missing Asana's task link.\n\nPlease append the Asana's task link relative to this commit into the commit message."
        exit 1
}
```

Each user needs to have a `commit-msg` file inside `.git/hooks`. Then, as a solution, I added `commit-msg` to the project folder (so I can pull this) with another file called `commit-msg-hook.sh` containing:

```
#!/bin/sh

cp commit-msg .git/hooks/commit-msg
chmod +x .git/hooks/commit-msg
echo "\nThe commit-msg hook was added to git hooks"
```

I welcome any advice to improve what I've done. Thanks.

Comment: Is it just me or is the 2nd line in the first code snippet not needed/not going to work. `chmod a+x .git/hooks/commit-msg` is to make the commit-msg executable, in order for it to run with git. But, the file (and thus that command) would never be able to execute if it did not already have `+x` so including this command in the actual file would not make sense. This post is from 2013, so anyone please correct me if im wrong. Surely someone else noticed this?

Comment: @Russell You are correct. I fixed it, it is being peer reviewed atm.